# Open-source ide for xml

Tags: windows, gratis, ide, xml

I'm looking for a free alternative to an xml IDE like XMLMind. I have not found any that meet my requirements. It needs to:

- Have syntax highlighting
- Have autocompletion
- Run on windows 10 (my OS)
- Be able to validate against a dtd and xsd schema
- Have a textual and graphical view
- Be completely free

Comment: Welcome aboard, and please do give my best regards to your father, Sir GoPythonJavaCppRuby the 2nd. You are missing quite a bit here, so please read [ask] and edit your question. Basically, the more detail you give us, the better we can help you.  Which operating system do you want this for (please add a tag)? Which specific features do you need (and which are “nice to have”)? If you expect us to know, or research, XMLMind then you will get fewer answers than if you state some detailed requirements.

Comment: Are you certain this must be [tag:open-source]? Unless you have security concerns or want to modify the source code, then probably not. In general it helps to specify a budget (not, of course, in the case of open source); if what you mean is that you don’t want to pay for it, then add the [tag:gratis] tag. Again, welcome aboard. I hope you get a satisfactory answer :-)

Comment: @Mawg you forgot the 3rd argument for open source: "I want to support the FOSS model/community by (only|preferably) choosing their products" :)

Comment: Guilty as charged :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Microsoft's FOSS [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) editor with Red Hat's [XML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-xml) extension.

Answer (score 2):

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) contains an XML editor which has all the features you mention. It is provided by the WST plugin which should be in most Eclipse packages you can download.

[image]